# Which IIS version Azure is running on?

Tags: .net, azure, iis

How do I figure out on which particular IIS version my Azure application will be running?

Can I choose to run my application only on a specific minimum IIS version in Azure, for example 8.0 or higher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't the IIS version depend on the version of Windows (2008, 2012 R2, etc.)?  For Cloud Services, you control the Windows OS version.

Comment: Ah, ok I did not know you can choose OS in Azure.

Comment: Yes - you control the Windows Azure OS family.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee924680.aspx for info on how the Windows Azure OS family maps to a Windows Server OS version, .NET, and SDK version.

Comment: What about Azure Websites? You don't get any of these choices in that scenario, apart from .Net framework version.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Looks like this question needs some more clarification for the case of Azure Website. I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999982/on-which-iis-version-azure-website-is-running-on

Answer (score 4):

Azure Websites is running on Microsoft-IIS/8.0. If You are using Cloud Service with instances, IIRC You can choose Windows OS version, but only from CLI (not from portal) - but I'm not sure.