# On which IIS version Azure Website is running on?

Tags: .net, iis, azure, cloud, version

Can I run my Azure website (not the Azure OS-instance) on a particular IIS version? For example on IIS 8.0 and later only?

Comment: It looks like that question is not clear enough. Please read the comment for the old question. I need it not for Azure OS-instance but for Azure webdsite.

Comment: In AzureWebsites you do not have control on IIS.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Websites is Microsoft-IIS/8.0 and using Azure Websites You are running Your site on it.

Comment: Please post the source of this information.

Comment: SERVER_SOFTWARE=Microsoft-IIS/8.0 from web app's kudu (scm) console.